# Can't export bookmark in google chrome mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks, export

Is it true that google chrome for mac can't export bookmarks to other browsers? I don't see any export link anywhere

Answer (score 3):

From the Bookmarks menu, choose Bookmark Manager. On the page that opens, click on the "Organize" menu. You should see an "Export Bookmarks..." item.

Note that I'm using version 5.0.375.23 dev -- that's from the Chrome [dev channel](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel). It's possible that the version of Chrome you're running doesn't have the bookmarks manager yet. It was added to the dev channel release in January ([TechCrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2010/01/14/chrome-for-mac-bookmarks/) about that release from Jan. 1, 2010).

Comment: Thanks, most of the Google results pointed to third party scripts and I overlooked this option completely in Chrome itself.